# Optimising query of unions and common conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have almost 18 unions of selects, each select contains almost 10 conditions which are identical just one condition differs. Please review sql structure below.

```
SELECT count(*) AS count, 'blue' as title 
FROM Users
WHERE [a long list of conditions,which are identical] AND eyes='blue'

UNION

SELECT count(*) AS count, 'hazel' as title 
FROM Users
WHERE [a long list of conditions,which are identical] AND eyes='hazel'

UNION

SELECT count(*) AS count, 'Black' as title 
FROM Users
WHERE [a long list of conditions,which are identical] AND eyes='black'
```

and so on.

What is the better way to retrieve such kind of data. Any better ideas ?

EDIT:

Sorry to not mention this earlier, these conditions are not based on single field "eyes", its can be different for example hairs,height etc. so group by can't be used as suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want condition sums:

```
select count(*),
       sum(case when eyes = 'blue' then 1 else 0 end) as blue,
       sum(case when eyes = 'hazel' then 1 else - end) as hazel,
       . . . 
from users
where <long list of conditions>
```

This will put everything on one row.  To get everything on separate rows, you probably want:

```
select eyes, count(*)
from users
where <long list of conditions>
group by eyes
```

This will give you a separate row for each eye color.

Based on your comments, the best approach is probably to summarize on a single row and then unpivot the values.  Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't have an unpivot, so the following, although ugly should be efficieint:

```
select titles.title,
       max(case when titles.title= 'blue' then blue
                when titles.title = 'hazel' then hazel
                . . .
           end) as cnt
from (select count(*) as cnt,
             sum(case when eyes = 'blue' then 1 else 0 end) as blue,
             sum(case when eyes = 'hazel' then 1 else - end) as hazel,
             . . . 
      from users
      where <long list of conditionss
     ) cross join
     (select 'blue' as title union all
      select 'hazel' union all
      . . .
     ) titles
group by titles.title
```

Comment: Oh i am so sorry to not mention is, its not just eyes, these may be different fields like hairs,eyes,height etc

Comment: @RasikhMashhadi . . . Then the first version that puts all the values in a row might be the best approach.  If you need separate rows, then would a user be counted exactly once on one row, or might a user be counted on multiple rows?

Comment: multiple rows would be better and user can be counted on multiple rows. Thanks in advance, your solutions sounds promising

Comment: Thanks. i changed my implementation a bit, and followed your first suggestion, it was brilliant.

Answer (score 2):

While this isn't the exact same output as you have above, but

```
select eyes, count(*)
from Users
where [a long list of conditions,which are identical]
group by eyes
```

Should give you the info you want.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to get the number of users for each eyes color you should try :

```
SELECT count( * ) AS c, 'eye'
FROM Users
WHERE .... all your conditions here ...
GROUP BY 'eye'
```